# Blending pineapples and coconuts whole, safety and experience?

Tags: food-safety, fruit, blender, pineapple, efficiency

A coconut and a pineapple are blended in their entirety, shell, leaves and all. Resulting in a smoothie like drink.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XbKCA1KUeqQ

Is this safe? As for example, it contains the woody part of the coconut.

How does the experience, such as taste and texture, differ from the usual, more selective approach?

Comment: It's fiber, which isn't all that uncommon to add to food and drinks.  (metamucil, sawdust (technically, 'powdered cellulose'), etc).  As it's ground up into a liquid, it probably goes down easier than the shell from fried peanuts.

Comment: Note that the video tells you not to try this at home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, the Blendtec, "will it blend" videos, are a marketing tool designed to illustrate the power of the product, as opposed to illustrating recipes for delicious smoothies.  Is it safe to drink?  There is nothing here: http://www.coconutresearchcenter.org/ that I have been able to find, which deems the "woody part" inedible or unsafe.  So, strictly speaking, that concoction is probably safe to drink (but I am no expert on coconut shells or pineapple leaves).  The more important question is, why would you want to?  I imagine the shell of the coconut and the outside of the pineapple would add bitterness and grassy flavors that would be off putting, plus, who wants to drink something that looks like that?  I further imagine the texture would be somewhat uncomfortable to swallow. It just doesn't look appetizing.  One of your tags is "efficiency."  There are reasons that we peel our fruits and veggies, even though it may be less convenient.  Safety may be one reason (maybe concern over pesticides?), but more often it is flavor and color that we are after.